# NoSQL for Finance Statement Generation

Tags: nosql, batch-processing, accounting

Does anybody know of any subsets of the finance/accounting domain that uses NoSQL?

In particular, I am wondering if there are projects in production that deals with statement and report generation, where the system relies on batch processing.

Traditionally, the batch jobs would be handled through SQL jobs or scheduled tasks.
The web interface is there to basically modify a whole bunch of parameters and then make the appropriate batch requests.

The reason I think NoSQL would be attractive is that the batch process sometimes deals with millions of rows of data in SQL to process the calculations.

Given the right settings, would this even be practical in NoSQL?

Again, I understand NoSQL has its purpose as does SQL, but I was wondering if NoSQL would be used in the finance statement generation if we are dealing with very large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Financial statements are just summaries of financial records, which are themselves just summaries of source documents like purchase orders and invoices.  Whatever database the financial records are stored in is the same one that gets queried for generating financial statements.  You can't really separate the two.  The only time you're going to see a nosql db used for financial statement generation is when a nosql db is used for financial record storage in the first place.  This is not impossible -- I haven't seen it yet, but I can see how it could be done; the nosql db could be used to store the source documents, and then its indexes would be equivalent to conventional accounting records.  There would need to be a way to make sure that index transactions are made up of sets of records in which the debits and credits balance, but again that could be done.